# Get count of related model efficiently in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a situation something like this (the actual code is bound up in a template, and omitted for brevity).

```
threads = Thread.objects.all()
for thread in threads:
    print(thread.comments.count())
    print(thread.upvotes.count())
```

I've managed to considerably reduce the total number of queries using Django's awesome `prefetch_related` method.

```
threads = Thread.objects.prefetch_related('comments').prefetch_related('upvotes')
```

However I'm wondering if this situation could be further optimized. From what I understand `prefetch_related` retrieves all of the data associated with the related models. Seeing as I only care about the amount of related models, and not about the models themselves, it seems like this query could be optimized further so that it doesn't retrieve a bunch of unnecessary data. Is there a way to do this in Django without dropping down to raw SQL?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're right, it's wasteful to fetch all that data from the database if all you want to do is get the count. I suggest annotation:

```
threads = (Thread.objects.annotate(Count('comments', distinct=True))
                         .annotate(Count('upvotes', distinct=True)))
for thread in threads:
    print(thread.comments__count)
    print(thread.upvotes__count)
```

See the [annotation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) for more information.

Comment: Awesome this does exactly what I wanted, thanks! Also searching through Django's docs it looks like 1.7 will be able to achieve something similar to what I described using the new Prefetch class and a custom query set that defers unused fields. However, your solution works with non bleeding edge versions of Django.

Comment: @rectangletangle: If all you care about is the count, annotation should still work better than `prefetch_related`. Even if you defer away everything but the id, there's no reason to fetch one integer for every comment when you can fetch one integer (the count) for every thread.

Comment: That's a good point. Between that and compatibility, I think you have the superior solution for this use case.

Comment: Anyway to get counts of a custom queryset? Like only counting published comments?

Comment: I came here looking for a solution where I do want to prefetch the count of a related field *while* querying a model. Unfortunately this doesn't answers OPs original question :(

Comment: @CollinAnderson: Sorry, just noticed your comment. Maybe the `filter` argument is what you're looking for? E.g. `Count('comments', filter=Q(comments__is_published=True))`. There are a couple examples on the [aggregation cheat sheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet).